# How do I pack regions into a folder in Logic Pro X?

Tags: logic

The Apple help site says:

> Select the regions, then choose Functions > Folder > Pack Folder from the Tracks area menu bar.

However, there is no Folder tab under Functions, nor is there any command in the menu bar or edit dropdown that says "Pack Folder."

This seems like a very simple thing, but I can't figure it out because following Apple's directions doesn't work. How do I pack and unpack folders?

I'm using the most recent version of Logic Pro X, so the YouTube tutorials I've found are unhelpful as they are older versions in which the Help site directions still work.

Answer (score 0):

This got answered on another site, but I figure I might was well share it here:

`Preferences > Advanced Tools... > Show Advanced Tools`

makes the option available. Why organizing with folders is an advanced tool is beyond me, but that's a discussion for another day.

Comment: Perhaps a link to the other site might be useful for others?